# Run custom command instead of browser when clicking http(s) links

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, putty, http, file-types

I am running a Fedora desktop with virtualised Windows 7 for certain programs that are needed for my daily work. One annoyance is that links in programs try to open with the default browser inside the VM, I would like to have them open in the host OS's browser instead.

I am able to launch a browser with link from the guest on the host with the following putty command and would like to register that as the protocol handler for http and https links:

```
putty.exe -ssh user@hostos "firefox -new-tab %U"
```

The problem is that cannot find a way to register that as the protocol handler for http and https links..

Comment: With the ssh keys in place and saved in a profile i can open a connection to the host and launch firefox as follows:

putty.exe -load openlinkonhost "DISPLAY=:0.0 firefox" 

But I can't find a way to pass the link that is clicked, windows sends %1 when opening in a local firefox but this doesn't get replaced when specifying it in the ssh command

Comment: Try to adopt [this solution](http://forums.techarena.in/technology-internet/1112113.htm). Change the path to your putty and add the arguments in the same manner he did for firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps to make this work are as follows (with firefox as default browser in the windows vm):

1. Configure [ssh keys in putty](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ssh-keys-with-putty-on-digitalocean-droplets-windows-users) and save the session with connection info to your host operating system
2. Create a batch script that runs plink.exe (command line version) like so:

   ```
   set PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\
   plink.exe -load mySavedSession "DISPLAY=":0.0 firefox -url '%3'"
   ```
3. Convert the batch script to a Windows executable. I used [an online converter](http://www.f2ko.de/en/ob2e.php) but you can do it any way you please
4. Save the new exe file as "firefox.exe" and replace (make a backup) the firefox executable in the program files directory

Clicking links in the VM will now open in the host browser.